# How can I change css for the React code depending on the Redux state (true or false)

Tags: css, reactjs, redux

I'm using the react-calendar. In the UI you can choose the starting date of a range. The end of the range is made automatically depending on what user choose. They can choose between 7, 14, 21, 28 days. In  component the range is set to false as if it is true user has to click second time and then I can't use automatic end date selection. This works fine.
But I've added a checkbox (with weekends). It should work in the way that if it is not checked the range excludes weekends. I can do it only visually changing the css file. I've prepared two css files where in one weekends background is white. The problem is that it works fine at the beginning. Then when I check the checkbox it shows the range with weekends but when i uncheck the checkbox nothing changes. I think I know where is the problem but I can't solve it...

The Calendar.js file:

```
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
//import './Calendar.css';
//I use default react-calendar css plus the customized one

import React from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

import { setDateAction } from "./calendarSlice";

export const CalendarFull = (props) => {
  const { chosenDate, chosenDuration, withWeekends, dispatch } = props;
    // I take the chosenDuration and pass through dispatch to use it in the calendar Reducer (setCurrentDateReducer)
    // where I need it for adding a range
    
  if (withWeekends === true) {
    const x = require('./Calendar.css');
  } else {
    const x = require("./Calendar1.css");
  }
  
  const onChangeSetDate = (date) => {
        dispatch(setDateAction(date, chosenDuration));
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar">
      <div className="calendar-container">
        <Calendar
          onChange={onChangeSetDate}
          value={chosenDate}
          minDate={new Date()}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The Calendar.css file:

```
.react-calendar { 
 width: 400px;
 max-width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #222;
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.125em;
 margin-top: 2rem;
 margin-left: 1rem;

}
.react-calendar__navigation button {
 color: #6f48eb;
 min-width: 44px;
 background: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: 8px;
}
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:focus {
 background-color: #f8f8fa;
}
.react-calendar__navigation button[disabled] {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
abbr[title] {
 text-decoration: none;
}
 .react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend {
 color: #d10000;
} 
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:focus {
 background: #6565b8;
 color: #6f48eb;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
.react-calendar__tile--now {
 background: white;
 border-radius: 6px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0d9924;
}
.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:focus {
 background: #6f48eb33;
 border-radius: 6px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
}
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:focus {
 background: #a4a4e2;
}
.react-calendar__tile--active {
 background: #6f48eb;
 border-radius: 6px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
}
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:focus {
 background: #a4a4e2;
 color: white;
}
.react-calendar--selectRange .react-calendar__tile--hover {
 background-color: #a8a8f3;
}
.react-calendar__tile--range {
 background: #a4a4e2;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 0;
}
/*.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend {
 color: #d10000;
 background-color: white;
}*/
.react-calendar__tile--rangeStart {
 border-top-right-radius: 0;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 6px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
 background: #a4a4e2;
 color: white;
}
.react-calendar__tile--rangeEnd {
 border-top-left-radius: 0;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 border-top-right-radius: 6px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
 background: #a4a4e2;
 color: white;
}
```

In the Calendar1.css at the end I have:

```
 .react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend {
 color: #d10000;
 background-color: white;
}
```

This is the only difference.

Is there any way to make it working or maybe some completly diffferent approach?

Comment: Lading css file based on state is a wrong way! You can load different style based on state by declaring different className in your jsx code something like this: className = { withWeekends ? 'class1' : 'class2'}

Comment: I did that. I've added class .react-calendar1 like that: className = { withWeekends ? 'react-calendar : 'react-calendar1'}.The Calendar.css had sth like that:      .react-calendar1__month-view__days__day--weekend {
 color: #d10000;
 background-color: white;    But it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a different approach and modified the Calendar.js file like that:

```
import './Calendar.css';
.
...
       return (   
         <div>
          <Calendar
            onChange={onChangeSetDate}
            value={chosenDate}
            minDate={new Date()}
            className={
              withWeekends
              ? "react-calendar"
              : "react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend1"
            }
          />
        </div>
);
```

and in the css file:

```
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend1 {
 color: #d10000;
 background-color: white;
}
```

I doesn't change weekends but changes the color of days of the week - like Mon, Tue, etc.
In a separate file the same changes weekends.
I'm quite confused and running out of ideas.

I've also tried:

```
 className={
              withWeekends
              ? "react-calendar"
              : "react-calendar1"
            }
```

with in css:

```
.react-calendar1__month-view__days__day--weekend {
 color: #d10000;
 background-color: white;
}
```

Result - nothing changes. I'm not good at BAM (quite bad I would say)...